# Can I construct a vector space whose scalar field is a complex algebra?

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, banach-algebras

A definition first:

A complex algebra is a vector space $X$ over the complex field $\mathcal{C}$ in which a multiplication is defined that satisfies:

$$
x(yz) = (xy)z \\
(x + y)z = xz + yz \\
x(y + z) = xy + xz
$$

and

$$
\alpha(xy) = (\alpha x) y = x (\alpha y)
$$

Unless I am missing something a complex algebra seems a stricter case of ring, my question is if there're any examples of vector spaces constructed over complex algebra or at least modules over complex algebras.

I cannot find much around, but I guess there must be examples.

**Clarification**: The question is if $A$ is a complex algebra over a vector space $X$ I wonder if we can construct a module/vector space $Y$ where the scalar field on $Y$ are elements of $X$.

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a $1$-dimensional algebra over $\Bbb C$, so a "complex algebra". In general such an associative algebra over the complex numbers need not be a field, of course. Consider dimension $2$, with basis $(x,y)$ and products $xx=x$, $xy=yx=0$ and $yy=y$. Extend the multiplication bilinearly to all vectors $\alpha x+\beta y$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I assume we can construct a module then, I don't see a reason why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: For every ring $A$ we can construct an $A$-module, yes. And the algebra $A$ here is already a vector space itself, as you said. Perhaps you should write again what exactly the question now is.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've updated the question, I think my question is more like "can I use the elements of a algebra over a field  (call $X$ such an algebra) to construct a vector space/module whose scalar ring/field are elements of $X$".

Comment: You can also extend any commutative ring to a field $\{[a/b] \mid a,b \in R, b \neq 0\}$ with $[a/b] = [c/d]$ iff $ad=bc$. But this gives "all elements of $X$ are in the scalar field of $Y$" instead of "the scalar field of $Y$ is $X$".